# laravel foreach input radiobutton displayed incorrectly

Tags: php, html, laravel, radio-button, laravel-blade

I'm trying to display the options for the questions. i have the problem that when im doing it this way:

```
@section('content')
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">Quiz: {{$category->name}}:</div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <form action="#" method="post" class="form-group">
      @csrf
      @foreach($questions as $key => $question)
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="question">Question {{1+$key}}:</label>
          <p class="card-text">{{$question->question_text}}</p>
          @foreach($question->option_text as $key => $option)
            <input type="radio">{{$option}}
          @endforeach
        </div>
        @endforeach
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

i can check all radio buttons at the same time but if i put there a name for the radiobutton i can check only one of the options for the whole questions.. i think there's something strange with the foreach loop..

Info: the table "questions" has the following rows:
id, category_id, question_text, correct_answer, option_text (this is a json-field that is casted to an array)

Code from Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request, Category $category){
  if($request->categoryTest == $category->name){
    $questions = $category->question()->inRandomOrder()->get();
    return view('user.test', compact('questions', 'category'));
  }
}
```

do you have an idea how to fix this? thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@section('content')
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">Quiz: {{$category->name}}:</div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <form action="#" method="post" class="form-group">
      @csrf
      @foreach($questions as $key => $question)
        @php
        $q = 1+$key
        @endphp
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="question">Question {{1+$key}}:</label>
          <p class="card-text">{{$question->question_text}}</p>
          @foreach($question->option_text as $key => $option)
            <input name="radio-{{$q}}" type="radio">{{$option}}
          @endforeach
        </div>
        @endforeach
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a normal behavior of the radio buttons, only one is market at time. Have you tried to use checkbox instead?

Also, if you want to send it to backend, you'll need to set a name attribute. And here is the magic: instead of using a singular name, put it as array in order to get an array on your controller.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="question[]" class="btn btn-primary">
```

Comment: i could try it with a checkbox thats right thank you! but i thought it would work properly with radio buttons too

Comment: I guess yes, but you need to keep in mind that radios are many options to pick just one of them. If you want to mark just one, that is fine - just put the name attribute (without []) and you'll get the value on your backend. One thing that I forgot to mention is that you need to set up the value attribute - this is the value you'll get on controller

Comment: as value i have set value="{{$option}}", now i should get the current option from the options array, am i right?

Comment: try something like <input name="selectedQuestion" value="{{$question->id}}" type="radio">{{$option}} then in the controller check the $request->input('selectedQuestion')... I think it would work.

Comment: it doesnt work, if i put the name to something like "selectedQuestion" then i can mark only one question option in the whole quiz, it's the same problem as i had at the beginning, but on the other hand now i know that it works too when i put the $question->id as name,  so i dont have to do it how serghei mentioned:)